# Estoy obteniendo la misma lista en un RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un Adapter creado y quiero rellenar dos RecyclerView "diferentes" pero que comparten el mismo diseño y los mismos atributos de clase. Entonces quería usar el mismo adapter para ambos recyclerview ya que me parecía poco útil crear dos diferentes, lo he hecho de la siguiente forma:

Este sería el código de mi Adapter:

```
    class EducationAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<EducationViewHolder>() {

    var education: MutableList<Education> = ArrayList()
    lateinit var context: Context

    fun EducationAdapter(education: MutableList<Education>, context: Context){

        this.education = education
        this.context = context

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): EducationViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return EducationViewHolder(
            layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.education_design,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return education.size

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EducationViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val item = education.get(position)
        holder.bind(item)

    }


}

class EducationViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val educationUrl = view.findViewById(R.id.ivEducationImage) as ImageView
    val educationTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tvEducationTitle) as TextView
    val educationPlace = view.findViewById(R.id.tvEducationPlace) as TextView
    val educationDesc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvEducationDescription) as TextView

    fun bind(education: Education){

        educationUrl.loadUrl(education.url)
        educationTitle.text = education.title
        educationPlace.text = education.place
        educationDesc.text = education.description

    }

    fun ImageView.loadUrl (url: String){

        Glide.with(context).load(url).transform(CenterCrop(), CircleCrop()).into(this)

    }

}
```

Este sería el código de mi clase donde quiero que se muestre los elementos del RecyclerView:

```
class EducationFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var mRecyclerViewAcademic: RecyclerView
    lateinit var mRecyclerViewComplementary: RecyclerView
    val mAdapter: EducationAdapter = EducationAdapter()

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): EducationFragment =
            EducationFragment()
    }

    fun setUpRecyclerView() {

        mRecyclerViewAcademic = rvEducationAcademic
        mRecyclerViewAcademic.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerViewAcademic.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        mAdapter.EducationAdapter(getEducationAcademic(), requireContext())
        mRecyclerViewAcademic.adapter = mAdapter

        mRecyclerViewComplementary = rvEducationComplementary
        mRecyclerViewComplementary.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerViewComplementary.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        mAdapter.EducationAdapter(getEducationComplementary(), requireContext())
        mRecyclerViewComplementary.adapter = mAdapter

    }

    fun getEducationAcademic(): MutableList<Education> {

        var educationAcademic: MutableList<Education> = ArrayList()

        educationAcademic.add(Education("https://einatec.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/errores-disenadores-graficos.jpg", "Prueba", "Prueba", "Prueba"))
        educationAcademic.add(Education("https://einatec.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/errores-disenadores-graficos.jpg", "Prueba", "Prueba", "Prueba"))

        return educationAcademic

    }

    fun getEducationComplementary(): MutableList<Education> {

        var educationComplementary: MutableList<Education> = ArrayList()

        educationComplementary.add(Education("https://cdn57.androidauthority.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Android-Studio-Coding2-840x473.jpg", "Prueba", "Prueba", "Prueba"))

        return educationComplementary

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_education, container, false)

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        setUpRecyclerView()

    }
}
```

En mi cabeza quedaba bien, pero claro, supongo que el problema está en que estoy usando una misma lista para ambos recyclerview, pero no tengo idea de como especificar una lista diferente dentro del adapter, ayuda a un principiante, gracias.

Comment: Lo que te falta es crear una instancia distinta para cada uno de los adapters

Comment: Pero solamente tengo un adapter @solamente

Comment: Tienes un adapter que puede tener 2 instancias: val mEducationAdapter: EducationAdapter = EducationAdapter(); val mComplementaryAdapter: EducationAdapter = EducationAdapter(); y asignarlos cada uno a su recycler

Comment: Vale si, lo estaba haciendo, solo que no había cambiado el nombre de la instancia en el segundo RecyclerView y no me estaba saliendo. Si quieres ponlo como respuesta y te la marco.

Comment: Estas usando la misma instancia del adapter por lo que estas obteniendo la misma lista, lo mejor seria crear un nueva instancia del adapter para cada uno de tus recycler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un adapter por lo que debes generar 2 instancias distintas de este y asignarlos a cada uno de los recyclers:

```
val mEducationAdapter: EducationAdapter = EducationAdapter(); 
val mComplementaryAdapter: EducationAdapter = EducationAdapter();
```